# MatPlotLib elapsed time axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

I'm trying to get my graph to display elapsed time on it's X axis, to display 10s of most recent data, as if to show a live feed. I'm not able to get it to display accurately, it is either way too fast or way too slow. Ive found a ton of examples about showing date/time on a graph, but that is useless to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's how I'm updating my graph:

```
def RealtimePloter(arg):
    global values1, values2, values3, manager, line1, line2, line3
    len_v = len(values1)
    x = np.arange(np.max([0, len_v - 100]), len_v)
    for ln, y in zip((line1, line2, line3), (values1, values2, values3)):
        ln[0].set_data(x, np.asarray(y[-100:]))
    ax.set_xlim([x[0], x[-1]])
    CurrentXAxis=pylab.arange(len(values1)-100, len(values1),1)
    ax.axis([CurrentXAxis.min(),CurrentXAxis.max(), -10, 10])
    manager.canvas.draw()

timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=10)
timer.add_callback(RealtimePloter, ())
```